# Proof for $ax + by \equiv 0 \pmod c$ implies $x\equiv 0 \pmod c$ and $y\equiv 0 \pmod c$ when $a,b$ are co-prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I believe this is true, but I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake in my rather informal proof below.

**Proof sketch:**
First, $ax+by \equiv 0\pmod c \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, ax+by = kc$.

Next, since $a,b$ are co-prime, we know that the only solutions to $ax+by = kc$ must be multiples of the Bezout coefficients $(s,t)$ such that $as + bt = 1$.
This means that $x = s(kc)p$ and $y=t(kc)q$ for some $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$, which implies $x\equiv 0 \pmod c$ and $y\equiv 0\pmod c$.<sup>*(This is the part I'm unsure about.)*</sup>

Am I making any mistakes or do you see an easier way to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is not true.

E.g. $ 2 \times 1 + 3 \times 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

---

Do you see where you made a reasoning error?

Comment: Eh, I suppose $k$ could be zero? In which case $x = b$ and $y = -a$ could be a solution that is not congruent to zero modulo $c$? So I didn't handle the case $k=0$ separately? So the proposition that " _the only solutions to $ax+by=kc$ must be multiples of the Bezout coefficients_" is actually false?

Comment: @Belo In addition to that, I have 2 concerns with your proof A) is "Bezout coefficients" unique? If not, what does this imply? B) Given a solution to ax+by=kc, why "must be multiple of Bezout coefficients" (E.g. in my counterexample).

Comment: Regarding (A), Bezout coefficients are not unique, so I suppose saying that the only solutions to $ax+by = kc$ when $a,b$ are coprime must be of the form $x=s(kc)p$ and $y=t(kc)q$ for some $p,q$ is not true because there are other solutions of the form $x=(s+ib)(kc)p$ and $y=(t-ia)(kc)q$ for any choice of $i$. However, these are still multiples of $c$... Regarding (B), I suppose you're saying that's not generally true.

Comment: @Bello Right, so if they are not unique, and their ratios are not unique, then which solution must they be a multiple of? This makes it less likely (though not impossible) that "solutions must be a multiple of some base case). But otherwise, it's good to form hypothesis and test them out to see if they are valid.